# Jquery select data-id from second row on table

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to make a table with a list of users for a school project.
I'm doing this with jquery, php and mysql.

I'm retrieving all data from the mysql database and printing it out in a table.
now i'm trying to add an update button to i can easily update data for each specific row.

This however is not working as expected. It only selects the data from the same row. While the data-id value is different. Could anyone tell me why this is happening? I'll leave my code below for clearance

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '#update-btn', function () {
       var id =$("[id='update-btn']").attr('data-id');
       var username = $('#username').val();
       var dob = $('#dob').val();
       var address = $('#address').val();

       $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/update.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
              ID: id,
              username: username,
              dob: dob,
              address: address
          },
          success: function (data) {
              if (data){
                  console.log(data);
                  swal({
                      title: 'Update successful',
                      icon: 'success',
                      text: 'User with ID ' + id + ' updated.'
                  });
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      window.location = 'medewerkers.php';
                  }, 5000)

              }
              else if (data === "update_failed"){

              }
          }
       });
   });
});
```

PHP:

```
public static function loadMedewerkers(){
$mysql = Database::DBCon()->prepare('

    SELECT * FROM medewerkers

');
$mysql->execute();

while ($fetch = $mysql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    $html = '<tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['username'] .'" id="username"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['dob'] .'" id="dob"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['address'] .'" id="address"</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="update-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Update</button></td>
             </tr>';
    echo $html;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your loop is causing multiple elements to have the same `id`, when `id` attributes *must* be unique within the DOM. To fix this use common classes on the elements within the loop, then DOM traversal to find them when the `button` is clicked.

```php
public static function loadMedewerkers()
{
  $mysql = Database::DBCon()->prepare('SELECT * FROM medewerkers');
  $mysql->execute();
  while ($fetch = $mysql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $html = '<tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['username'] .'" class="username"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['dob'] .'" class="dob"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['address'] .'" class="address"</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning update-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Update</button></td>
    </tr>';
    echo $html;
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.update-btn', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var username = $row.find('.username').val();
    var dob = $row.find('.dob').val();
    var address = $row.find('.address').val();

    // ajax request here...
  });
});
```

Note the use of `data()` to retrieve the `data` attribute. Also note that you could put the `data-id` attribute itself on the `tr` instead of each `button` to DRY up the HTML slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID in your buttons when returning
ID is unique for each object in the screen
try using class
something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.update-btn', function () {
       var id =$(this).data('id');
       var username = $(this).closest('tr').find('.username').val();
       var dob = $(this).closest('tr').find('.dob').val();
       var address = $(this).closest('tr').find('.address').val();

       $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/update.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
              ID: id,
              username: username,
              dob: dob,
              address: address
          },
          success: function (data) {
              if (data){
                  console.log(data);
                  swal({
                      title: 'Update successful',
                      icon: 'success',
                      text: 'User with ID ' + id + ' updated.'
                  });
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      window.location = 'medewerkers.php';
                  }, 5000)

              }
              else if (data === "update_failed"){

              }
          }
       });
   });
});



public static function loadMedewerkers(){
$mysql = Database::DBCon()->prepare('

    SELECT * FROM medewerkers

');
$mysql->execute();

while ($fetch = $mysql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    $html = '<tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['username'] .'" class="username"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['dob'] .'" class="dob"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="'. $fetch['address'] .'" class="address"</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning update-btn" data-id="'. $fetch['ID'] .'">Update</button></td>
             </tr>';
    echo $html;
}
}
```

same goes for your delete button

and use .data() instead of attr()

Also, in other columns for getting the username, dob and address you have to use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: This still uses `id` attributes...?

Comment: data-id is fine its for your jquery, attr id for your button tag was not fine

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean, but my comment is referring to `$('#username').val()` etc.